# The specified path is not valid

Tags: powershell, path

I am in a windows console or powershell. (Windows7 x64 Pro, PowerShell 4)

When i try to type command like "cmd" i have an error message "The specified path is not valid"

```
PS D:\DevEnv\workspace\api-node> cmd
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All right reserved.
The specified path is not valid.
```

What i tryed after reading msdn articles but it don't solve the problem:

-delete my System variable PATH and try again

-clean my registry with ccleaner

Is there any "verbose" or "debug" mode in powershell or windows console to see what path is involved and where i can change it?

Comment: Don't delete your system PATH variable. Also, why do you want to start cmd.exe? You're already at a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: What's the output of `gcm cmd | select Definition, Source` ?

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any "verbose" or "debug" mode …?* I don't think so; however, running next commands from an open `cmd` window could help to identify possible error source(s):

```
wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get Caption, CommandLine, ParentProcessId, ProcessId
2>NUL reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V AutoRun
2>NUL reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V AutoRun
```

In above output we are seeking for any commands which could be a source of `The specified path is not valid` error message.

- `wmic` seems to be self-explaining;
- both `reg query` show `AutoRun` registry values (if present), see `cmd /?`.